# Restore hard disk signature

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning, mbr

I have put my desktop hard drive into another machine. To make it usable I had to go to Device Manager and click *Online*.

[image]

[image]

When I put my hard drive back into the old PC, I am not able to boot the PC. Is there any fix available?

**EDIT:**
Can this could be fixed with `fdisk/fixmbr` with windows repair disk. What is community advice?

Comment: Did you check this article already? [Fixing Disk Signature Collisions](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2011/11/08/3463572.aspx)

Comment: @and31415, Yes I went though that article, Mark says `0x38 (remember to reverse the order of the bytes)` Couldn't understand that part.

Comment: Take the four bytes (pairs of hexadecimal digits) found at offset 0x38 in the registry binary data, as described in that article, and reverse the order of the bytes (i.e. last byte first, etc). Use the resulting string of 8 hexadecimal digits as the disk signature you restore using DISKPART at the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I booted up from windows 8 disk and selected startup repair. It did not help.

I just recovered my OS & app installations by following [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2011/11/08/3463572.aspx)

1. Booted up from windows disk in repair mode
2. On command prompt open regedit
3. Loaded C:\Boot\BCD into hive
4. Obtained disk signature by searching `Windows boot manager`
5. Revers hex byte order
6. Goto DiskPart select hard-disk
7. Assign reveresed byte order disksignature as unique id.

Done.

P.S. Follow above for better explanation & steps with screen-shot.